# difference of "String" object, and string literal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, firebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between the javascript String Type and String Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051833/difference-between-the-javascript-string-type-and-string-object)

Write this simple code in Firebug:

```
console.log(new String("string instance"));
console.log("string instance");
```

What you see is:

[image]

Why these two `console.log()` calls result in different output? Why string literal is not the same as creating a string through `String` object? Is it a Firebug representation style? Or do they differ in nature?

Comment: Please visit the post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051833/difference-between-the-javascript-string-type-and-string-object

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal duplicates don't warrant downvotes, just vote to close as duplicate if you have the rep, or just point it out and someone else will.

Comment: @Davy8: Yes they do. It's the most obvious indication of "no research effort". I closevoted _and_ downvoted, as is usual. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They differ. A string literal is a primitive value, while a "String" instance is an object.  The primitive string type is promoted automatically to a String object when necessary.

Similarly, there are numeric primitives and "Number" instances, and boolean primitives and "Boolean" instances.

Comment: For what it's worth, to get a string literal from a String object, you can call the `toString()` function on the String object. 

For example, `new String("bork") === "bork"` is false, while `new String("bork").toString() === "bork"` is true.

Oh, javascript...

Comment: And how does this "promotion" occur?

Answer (score 2):

`new String("...")` returns a string **object**.

`"..."` returns a string **primitive**.

Some differences are:

- `new String("foo") === new String("foo")` - `false`; object reference equality rules
- `"foo" === "foo"` - `true`; string equality rules

and:

- `new String("foo") instanceof Object` - `true`; it's an object derived from `Object`
- `"foo" instanceof Object` - `false`; it's not an object but a primitive value

Most of the times you just want a primitive value because of these "quirks". Note that string objects are converted into primitive strings automatically when adding them, calling `String.prototype` functions on them etc.

More information [in the specs](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.2.1).

Answer (score 1):

`console.log("string instance");` prints string litral but `console.log(new String("string instance"));` is object so its printing all the details of string like each index and character. Watch out the screen shot below, its showing each character of `"string instance"`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try `console.log((new String("string instance")).toString())`

Anyways, it's because `new String("string instance")` is an Object, and console.log doesn't automatically stringify objects