# Javascript Undefined String Property Truthiness

Tags: javascript, truthiness

I've often used the following pattern in my Javascript:

```
x = couldBeNullThing || valueIfItIsNull;
```

because it beats than:

```
x = couldBeNullThing ? couldBeNullThing : valueIfItIsNull;
```

I also frequently use a slight variant of that same pattern:

```
x = x || valueIfXIsNotDefined;
```

That's all great ... except the problem is, I recently discovered:

```
foo = "";
//assert foo.x === undefined;
foo.x = foo.x || valueIfXIsNotDefined;
//assert foo.x === undefined;
```

In other words, if you have a string, and you do string.aPropertyThatStringDoesntHave || foo, you'll get back neither foo nor an actual value; instead you get undefined.

Can anyone explain why this is?  It seems to me that if foo.x is undefined, then foo.x || anythingElse should always result in anythingElse ... so why doesn't it?

Comment: Interestingly, it seems to work if you do `foo = new String("")`

Comment: Another thing I noticed, is that using `console.log(foo)` returns  "(an empty string)", and when using new String("") it returns a String object. Also, I'm on Firefox. May be different on other browsers.

Comment: Ugh sorry for spamming. But it's an interesting question. Also `foo = String("")` returns "(an empty string"). And additionally doing something like `foo = "Test".substr(1)` returns just a string value and not an object.

Comment: Anyway this may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051833/difference-between-the-javascript-string-type-and-string-object

Comment: For an empty string `s`, `s.no_such_property` gives me `undefined` as expected and `s.no_such_property || 11` gives me `11` as expected. I get the same (expected) results in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. What am I supposed to be seeing? Am I looking at the wrong thing? http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8wwUh/

Comment: ^I think it has to do with his pattern of `x = x || valueIfXIsNotDefined`. So if you do `foo.x = foo.x || valueIfXIsNotDefined` and then do `console.log(foo.x)` you will get undefined. I think this is because foo is just a plain string literal and not an object.

Comment: Works as expected for me: http://jsfiddle.net/xxLtP/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm familiar with the concept of `assert` I wasn't aware that JavaScript had that functionality. So with that in mind I could be completely wrong but it seems to me that this statement:

```
assert (foo.x || valueIfXIsNotDefined) === undefined;
```

...is calling a function called `assert()`, passing it the parameter `foo.x || valueIfXIsNotDefined` and then comparing the return value from the `assert()` function with `undefined`. Perhaps what you need is this:

```
assert(foo.x || valueIfXIsNotDefined === undefined);
```

If I try something similar with `console.log()`:

```
var foo = "",
    valueIfXIsNotDefined = "test";
console.log( foo.x === undefined);
console.log(foo.x || valueIfXIsNotDefined === undefined);
```

​Then it logs:

```
true
false
```

Similarly, after:

```
var result = foo.x || valueIfXIsNotDefined;
```

`result` is `"test"`.

http://jsfiddle.net/YBPyw/

Further, if you actually try to assign `foo.x` equal to something (where `foo` was a string) it doesn't work, so when you later test `foo.x` it will give `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct that JS doesn't have a native assert.  I was just trying to explain the situation, but I really should have said "// assert .." to be clearer (I'll edit the question).  Your final sentence answered my question (thanks), but it took the comments from Gohn67 to understand it.  For other readers, as I understand it the reason var foo = ""; foo.x = 1; foo.x != 1; is because in the second statement foo gets temporarily converted in to new String(foo).  This allows it to get an x property assigned to it, but then afterward it goes back to being a (property-less) primitive.