# [] is an instance of Array but "" isn't of String

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does instanceof return false for some literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203739/why-does-instanceof-return-false-for-some-literals)

If I do...

```
[] instanceof Array;
```

...it returns `true` although I haven't used `new Array()`.

But if I do...

```
"" instanceof String;
```

...it returns `false` because  I haven't used `new String()`.

Why? I understand that `[]` is a language construct for creating arrays and `""` is a language construct for creating strings. So I don't understand why one returns `true` and the other returns `false`.

Moreover, all of the following codes return `true`:

```
[] instanceof Array; /* true */
Array() instanceof Array; /* true */
new Array() instanceof Array; /* true */
```

But with strings:

```
"" instanceof String; /* false */
String() instanceof String; /* false */
new String() instanceof String; /* true */
```

Shouldn't `String() instanceof String` return `true` too?

**Edit:**

I have made a new question (spin-off of this one): [Easy way to check if a variable is a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254882/easy-way-to-check-if-a-variable-is-a-string)

Comment: It _is_ a bit confusing. If you want to test if `something` is a string you can do `typeof something === "string"`. You'll find `typeof "" === "string"` will be `true`.

Comment: "Should" is a tricky word; do you mean "should" as in "JavaScript is intrinsically broken," or "should" as in "it doesn't meet with my expectations", or "should" as in something said it should, but it doesn't? In any case, strings are a value type in JS; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051833/difference-between-the-javascript-string-type-and-string-object) for more details.

Comment: A `string` value is not a `String` value although it shares the `[[prototype]]` .. (same for `number` vs. `Number`, etc.)

Comment: @pst I don't think that's true - what happens is that a string constant is promoted to a String object when necessary - like when it's used as the left operand of the `.` operator. String constants and numbers don't have a prototype because they're not objects.

Comment: @nnnnnn But your code doesn't work with `new String()`. Must I do `typeof abc === "string" || abc instanceof String` each time I want to check if a variable `abc` is a string?

Comment: Yes, sorry, but why would you ever actually use `new String()`?

Comment: @Pointy Given `String.prototype.me = function () { return this; }`, then `"".me() === ""` agrees with your last comment as `typeof "".me()` yields "object" (in FF14), but I am not well versed in this aspected of the ECMAScript specification. IIRC I thought this behavior was a "bug" of an implementation, from a vague memory of a previous SO post ..