# Working of valueOf method in different object

Tags: javascript

FirstOfAll plz help me provide info of working of valueOf method in different object.

Is there a difference between `String.prototype.valueOf`and 
`Object.prototype.valueOf` method,if there exist difference why 
not seen when `Object.prototype.valueOf.call("maizere")`.Since valueOf here is the method of `Object.prototype` not `String.protototype` but it outputs string rather than `[object String]`.Shouldn't it output `[object String]`?It seems as if the valueOf method belongs to `String.prototype` since it outputs *string*.Thank u for ur help

Comment: `Object.prototype.valueOf === String.prototype.valueOf` is `false`.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville no ,{}.valueOf() returns array i.e [object Object]

Comment: @Blender Is that necessary here?

Comment: Well, yes. `Array.prototype.valueOf === Object.prototype.valueOf` is `true`, as they're the same method. The other one is `false` because they're not.

Comment: @Blender if there exist difference why not seen when Object.prototype.valueOf.call("maizere") which was my question

Comment: What do you mean "why not seen when Object.prototype.valueOf.call("maizere")"? That doesn't really return the predicted result, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference here is between [strings and string objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051833/difference-between-the-javascript-string-type-and-string-object):

```
> typeof String('foo')
"string"
> typeof new String('foo')
"object"
> "foo" === String('foo')
true
> "foo" === new String('foo')
false
> String.prototype.valueOf.call("maizere")
"maizere"
> Object.prototype.valueOf.call("maizere")
String {0: "m", 1: "a", 2: "i", 3: "z", 4: "e", 5: "r", 6: "e", format: function, truncate: function, splitOnLast: function, contains: function}
```

`String`'s `valueOf` returns a string and `Object`'s `valueOf` returns an object, which in this case is a string object. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: isn't valueOf method of Object.prototype supposed to return [object objectName] ,than why is it returning string object .It should all the time return [object ObjectName] isn't it?

Comment: @Maizere: Open up Chrome's console and try it again. It doesn't return `[object ObjectName]`.

Comment: so than shall i consider that If an object has no primitive value only than valueOf returns the object itself, which is displayed as:[object object] else only object

Comment: @Maizere: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: also why console.log(Object.prototype.valueOf.call([])) outputs blank ?shouldn't it alert[object Object] since it is empty .Reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)

Comment: @Maizere: You have to call `Object.prototype.toString.call(Object.prototype.valueOf.call([]))`.