# saving values in two dimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have seen other questions and all examples are like below

```
var arr = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5];

alert (arr[2][1]);
```

But i want somethingl ike this

```
var mmo = [];

mmo["name"] = "steve";
mmo["name"]["x"] = "20";
mmo["name"]["y"] = "40";

alert(mmo["name"]["y"]); // should alert 40 but its undefined
```

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to have additional properties on a string. However, you can do the above, if you create it like `mmo["name"] = new String("steve");`

Comment: And this answer explains it rather well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2051893/921204

Answer (score 2):

You can't have both a value and an array in the same item.

Use an object instead of an array, as you want to use named propertes insted of numeric indices.

Put an object as the property, then you can put properties in that object:

```
var mmo = {};

mmo["name"] = {};
mmo["name"]["x"] = "20";
mmo["name"]["y"] = "40";
```

If you want to use an array in the object, then you would use numeric indices:

```
var mmo = {};

mmo["name"] = [];
mmo["name"][0] = "20";
mmo["name"][1] = "40";
```

If you want to use an array in an array, then it would all be numeric indices:

```
var mmo = [];

mmo[0] = [];
mmo[0][0] = "20";
mmo[0][1] = "40";
```

An array is also an object, so you *could* use an array and put properties in it, but that is mostly confusing.