# Difference between e.g. 'message' and new String('message') in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, constructor

[Difference between the javascript String Type and String Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051833/difference-between-the-javascript-string-type-and-string-object) does not include case 2.

---

All of these expressions seem to do mostly the same thing.  How are they different?

1. `'message'`
2. `String('message');`
3. `new String('message');`

Comment: `new String('message') !== 'message'` is the big one.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051833/difference-between-the-javascript-string-type-and-string-object

Comment: Never do `2` and `3`. Never. (Well maybe in some cases you would use it but normally you don't and you shouldn't) If you use it and you don't know what you're doing you will get mysterious errors in your code.

Comment: In what situations do `2` and `3` break things but `1` does not?

Comment: @user2357112  Are there situations in which `2` and `3` behave differently?

Comment: `String('message')` is equivalent to `'message'`, so it has all the differences with `new String('message')` that `'message'` does.

Answer (score -1):

Basically `'message'` is just a string litrel. You can just use `String` functions on that.
What I know that `String('message')` & `'message'` are same.

But on `new String()` create a new Object of type `String`. So you will be able to define your `properties` & `methods` on it.

Like bellow

```
var msg = new String('message');
msg.sender = "Someone".
msg.sender //returns "Someone"

var msg = String('message');
msg.sender = "Someone".
msg.sender //returns undefined

var msg = 'message';
msg.sender = "Someone".
msg.sender //returns undefined
```

But you can't do sane on litrels.

Comment: What is the difference between `String('message')` and `new String('message')`?

Comment: @jnylen What I know that `String('message')` & 'message` are same.