# Why is string = '0' not strictly equal to new String('0') in javascript

Tags: javascript

Why does the creation of a string object not return true when compared strictly to a primitive string value?

```
var obj = new String('0');
var str = '0';

console.log(obj == str); //returns true
console.log(obj === str); //returns false
```

Comment: Do a `typeof` on each variable.  The first is an `object`.  The second is a `string`.

Comment: It might help to also read the difference between the identity === operator and the equality operator == as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons and quite a few other SE posts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As `obj` type is `object` where `str` is `string`, Hence `obj === str` is `false`.

```js
var obj = new String('0');
var str = '0';

console.log(typeof obj);
console.log(typeof str);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does var str = '0' have a prototype?

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(obj == str); //returns true
console.log(obj === str); //returns false
```

Identity and equals operators is quite different things. Second case is very simple, because object can't be identical to string.
First case evolves boxing/unboxing mechanism, and result value is dependent on operator in expression. In this example, because `str` is primitive, `obj` will be unboxed, and comparation will success.

Expression `new String('xxx') == new String('xxx')` , of course, will be false, because there is no primitive value to force convert to it's type.
See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp for details.

Answer (score 0):

`String Object` and `String type value` are are not the same that is why '===' gives `false`

If you are making a string object, it is different than a string type value.

```
var obj = new String('0'); // this is object type
var str = '0';             // this is string type value
```

when you use '===' that is strict equality,

> Strict equality compares two values for equality. Neither value is implicitly converted to some other value before being compared. If the values have different types, the values are considered unequal.
>   [Read More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

That's why when you use '==='(strictly compare) it returns `false`

Check this answer to see difference between string object and string type value, [Difference between the javascript String Type and String Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2051893/5236174)