# Is auto-boxing a form of type coercion?

Tags: javascript

Type coercion is the implicit type conversion of an operand by an operator.

IIUC, when evaluating `'a'.length`, `a` is temporarily wrapped, or boxed, in a instance of `String`, which is (?) strictly a different type to a string literal.

Is type coercion involved here?

```js
console.log(typeof new String('') === typeof '') // false
```

Comment: new String('') is instance of String object, '' is just string

Comment: same as `new String("") === new String("")`

Comment: not sure what .length has to do with typeof a String Object.  You have `console.log("object" === "string")`

Comment: `new String("").toString() === new String("").toString() // True`

Comment: @epascarello the type of the string literal `'a'` does not have a property `length`. The `String` type does, however, have such a method on its prototype. Maybe this question boils down to: is a string literal a different type from its constructor-created counterpart? `typeof` suggests it is different.

Comment: Well length is not a method to start.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051833/difference-between-the-javascript-string-type-and-string-object

Comment: I think the question is, "Is auto-boxing a form of type coercion?"

Comment: And the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2051862/14104 points to the rules on how the property of the string is fetched.

Comment: Your definition of `auto-boxing` and `type coercion` are not clear. When you access a property of a javascript primitive type other than `object` then it gets `wrapped` using the appropriate wrapper for that primitive type. https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-getv

Comment: Thank you Robert. Happy to add clarification where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

## Is auto-boxing a form of type coercion?

Your definition of `auto-boxing` and `type coercion` are not clear. As far as I know `auto-boxing` isn't a Javascript concept.

On MDN `type coercion` is defined as "[the automatic or implicit conversion of values from one data type to another](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion)".

Usually the term is only used in the context of operators other than property access. But when you access a property of a javascript primitive type other than [`object` or `undefined`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-requireobjectcoercible) then it gets [wrapped](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-getv) using the appropriate wrapper for that primitive type. And this operation involves `type coercion`.

In non-strict mode the wrapping happens again when you actually call the function to produce a `this` of object type, while in strict mode `this` is of the original type.

## Does `console.log(typeof new String('') === typeof '')` involve type coercion?

No. There is no coercion involved:

`new String('')` produces a string object.

`typeof aStringObject` produces the string primitive `"object"`.

`typeof ''` produces the string primitive `"string"`.

`"object" === "string"` produces the boolean primitive `false`.

`console.log` can only output strings, but Javascript function parameters have no types. The [implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/master/lib/util.js#L390) of `console.log(false)` probably uses `type coercion` or explicit [type conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_conversion) to convert the boolean value `false` to the string value `"false"` though.

Comment: This is the only answer I could find that explains why e.g. `(2).toString()` works - because the spec says property access converts to object before trying to access a property.

Comment: @G.Bach Why shouldn't it work? The only reason why `2.toString()` does not work is because the parser always interprets the first dot as a decimal separator. Even `2..toString()` works. I'm sure most people never actually used String/Number/etc objects but still used their methods. That's the normal usage and the specs somehow evolved around that habit. When you try to access the properties of a primitive, you access the properties of a wrapper.

Comment: Yes, I know; but that difference between `2.toString()` and `(2).toString()` is what I couldn't figure out with the info found elsewhere.